# MD-LIST Constant Height

Tags: javascript, css, angular, material-design, angular-material

I want to implement some simple chat using md-list as template for this.
The problem is when I am adding new items to md-list (pushing new messages) the md-list is growing.

I want to have behaviour of my list similiar to some other chats, so the chat height is constant, independent of items count and the chat is scrollable in Y so, the users, can se older message by scroll.

I alread set this:

```
    md-list{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And set the container of chat to some max-height value, but the list is growing, and going out of the parent sizes.

So the parent is on init 400px height, chat too. When i add messages the parent has always 400px height, but chat is growing += message.height.

How to fix it?
I try to add max-height the same as initial height of chat, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Angular 2.x/4.x or AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Add class with fixed height to md-list.

```
      <md-list class="fix-height">          
        <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">3 line item (with hover)</md-subheader>
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in todos" ng-click="null">
          <img ng-src="{{item.face}}?{{$index}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}">
          <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
            <h3>{{ item.who }}</h3>
            <h4>{{ item.what }}</h4>
            <p>{{ item.notes }}</p>
          </div>
        </md-list-item> 
      </md-list>
```

CSS

```
.fix-height{
  max-height:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YreJLy?editors=1100)